# ClassNotFoundException when trying to deploy with JNLP?

Tags: java, maven, java-web-start, jnlp

I have an application written in Java that uses Maven to build. I'd like to deploy it using JNLP. This is the folder structure I have:

```
MyProject
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   ├── folder
│   │   │   │   ├── to
│   │   │   │   │   ├── my
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── project
│   │   │   │   │   │   │   ├── ClassWithMain.java
│   │   ├── jnlp
│   │   │   ├── myjnlp.jnlp
│   │   │   ├── myjar.jar
│   │   │   ├── mymanifest.txt
│   │   │   ├── keystore
│   │   │   ├── pageToLaunchJnlp.html
├── target
│   ├── classes
│   │   ├── folder
│   │   │   ├── to
│   │   │   │   ├── my
│   │   │   │   │   ├── project
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── ClassWithMain.class
```

I created the jar using mymanifest.txt and the ClassWithMain.class from within the target folder, and I signed it using the keystore and a timestamp url.

There are other files besides ClassWithMain, but that's the one with the main method.

But when I try to run the jnlp file, I get the error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: folder.to.my.project.ClassWithMain
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.doLaunchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here's my jnlp file below. I took out the codebase attribute since I saw the tutorial of deploying without a codebase at this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/deployingWithoutCodebase.html). My HTML file uses the launchWebStartApplication and createWebStartLaunchButtonEx functions, but I still get the ClassNotFoundException.

I've tried changing it to `main.java.folder.to.my.project.ClassWithMain`, but that doesn't work either.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0"
      href="myjnlp.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>My Project</title>
        <description>My Project Webstart</description>
        <offline-allowed/>
    </information>
    <security>
        <sandbox/>
    </security>

    <resources>
        <j2se href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" version="1.6+" initial-heap-size="512m"
              max-heap-size="512m"/>
        <property name="sun.java2d.noddraw" value="true"/>
        <jar href="myjar.jar" main="true"/>
    </resources>
    <application-desc main-class="folder.to.my.project.ClassWithMain"/>
</jnlp>
```

Here's where my ClassWithMain is located according to the `jar tvf`command: 
`Users/myusername/MyProject/target/classes/folder/to/my/project/ClassWithMain.class`

Is this an issue with my folder structure, and if so, what is the correct structure/location for the jnlp file, jar file, keystore, etc. so the main class file is detected properly?

Thanks, any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's very unusual to see a jar under the src hierarchy. I don't use maven, but I can't imagine that's where it should go

Comment: Please provide a `jar tvf`listing of the JAR file that shows where the .class file is located.

Comment: @syim your folder structure in not as expected by maven, you should keep all non java files(jnlp file) in resource directory instead anywhere else

Comment: @syim please refer answer, and please tell mnifest and jar file where you want you in your build, i will try to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your folder structure should be like this -

```
MyProject
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   ├── folder
│   │   │   │   ├── to
│   │   │   │   │   ├── my
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── project
│   │   │   │   │   │   │   ├── ClassWithMain.java
            resources
            ├── folder
            │   ├── to
            │   │   ├── my
            │   │   │   ├── project
                            ├── myjnlp.jnlp
                            ├── myjar.jar
                            ├── mymanifest.txt
                            ├── keystore
                            ├── pageToLaunchJnlp.html
```

you will get

```
├── target
│   ├── classes
│   │   ├── folder
│   │   │   ├── to
│   │   │   │   ├── my
│   │   │   │   │   ├── project
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── ClassWithMain.class
                        ├── myjnlp.jnlp
                        ├── mymanifest.txt
                        ├── pageToLaunchJnlp.html
```

At the run time myjnlp.jnlp will get ClassWithMain.class at same location.
And yes I doubt about your jar location it should not be where you were showing, second think keystore, why you need to keep in build ? if you need it should be move to meta-inf of your build.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So I moved everything as you said and did mvn clean package again so the jnlp, jar, and other files ended up in the target folder like you said they would. I still get the ClassNotFoundException however.  Also, where would be a better place to put the jar file?

Comment: why do you need jar to be keep in build ? and please share exception stack trace

Comment: From what I've read, maven actually does expect jnlp stuff to be where he had it, under the src directory. The issue as far as I can tell is that that jar is a build artifact that needs to be in the classpath and shouldn't be undert the src tree at all, but in a /build, /bin/, /out whatever directory. Whatever class it can't find is not in the classpath as configured by the jar's manifest.xml

Comment: @Novaterata correct, syim  you should not keep build artifact in src directory anyway.

Comment: Ok yes I removed the jar from src and moved a few things around, and now I think I got it working! I had to put mymanifest.txt, the html, and jnlp files in src/main/resources so mvn clean package resulted in the files being in target/classes. Within target/classes, I made a jar using the folder/ as the input-files. The jar doesn't seem to run into a ClassNotFound Exception. Thanks for the help!

Comment: With maven, you shouldn't have to "make a jar" it should just make one for you. Are you using the jar plugin?

Comment: My application uses the antrun plugin to run so the snapshot jar it makes isn't actually used. I made the jar following a tutorial to try out deployment using JNLP, and that's where the issues with file locations/directories came up.

Comment: @syim is this your problem get solve for ClassNotFound Exception ?

Comment: Yes, I'll go ahead and mark your answer since it helped me out a lot! Thanks again